# python post url with requests.Session

Tags: python, post, request

I am trying to download a file with python using "requests.Session" in order to take cookies into account.

My following code return the source code of the second webpage but does not download the file... even if I have included the header and the parameters...
I am running out of idea to find the problem here ...

```
s = requests.Session()
url_euronex = "https://www.euronext.com/equities/directory"
response = s.get(url_euronex)
response_code = response.status_code
if response_code==200:
    content = response.text
    token = content[content.index('formKey=nyx_pd_filter_values:')+29 : content.index('dataTableInitCallback')-3]

    url = "https://www.euronext.com/fr/popup/data/download?ml=nyx_pd_stocks&cmd=default&formKey=nyx_pd_filter_values%3A"+str(token)
    print(url)
    headers = {
        'Host':'www.euronext.com',
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0',
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer':url,
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length':'135',
        'Connection':'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1'}

    Params = {'Query string':{'ml':'nyx_pd_stocks', 'cmd':'default', 'formKey':'nyx_pd_filter_values:'+str(token)}, 'Form data':{'format':'3','layout':'2','decimal_separator':'1','date_format':'1','op':'Go','form_build_id':'form-64080cce1044e288464d174290cb40e9','form_id':'nyx_download_form'}}

    data = [{'url': url, 'params': Params, 'method': 'post'}]
    r = s.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)

    if r.status_code==200:
        print('coucou')
        #resultat = (r.text).encode('utf-8')
        print(r.text)
```